# Кнопка отправки данных должна отправлять данные в 2 места

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Есть необходимость отправлять данные из формы в CRM и я даже знаю как это сделать, если речь про php, но в данный момент есть а) плагин Contact Form 7 для wordpress б) я так понимаю, плагин отправляет данные посредством JS, плюс, у него есть дополнительная настройка - можно вписать событие на кнопку отправки (например, переадресация на другую страницу).

Меня интересует, впишется ли моя задача в рамки функции на кнопку отправки данных и как это будет называться?

Если нет, то что тут можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, Contact Form 7 отправляет данные через ajax. По нажатию кнопки срабатывает функция onclick, которая через ajax вызывает выполнение кода php на сервере. Оттуда и отправляется письмо с помощью wp_mail().

Во-вторых, в Contact Form 7 есть настройка, чтобы отправлять письмо в другой адрес (вкладка Письмо, внизу - письмо 2). Там можно указать хоть 10 дополнительных адресатов в поле Кому.

В-третьих, есть хуки Contact From 7, срабатывающие в момент отправки почты. Их можно перехватить и сделать что-то свое.